# PostgreSQL: How do I join same table multiple times and take data?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, count

The table I have is this:

| C1 | C2 | userid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 100 |
| 2 | 40 | 101 |
| 3 | 30 | 102 |
| 4 | 20 | 103 |
| 5 | 10 | 104 |

I need the `userid` and `count()` userid `WHERE` (Condition satisfied)
by input

```
userid IN (100,101,102,103,104,105)
```

The condition is :

```
 C1 > (input userid's C1) and C2 < (input userid's C2)
```

I need it like this :

| userid | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 4 |
| 101 | 3 |
| 102 | 2 |
| 103 | 1 |

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join and aggregate as the following:

```
SELECT D.userid, COUNT(*) cnt 
FROM table_name T JOIN table_name D
ON T.C1 > D.C1 AND T.C2 < D.C2
WHERE D.userid IN (100,101,102,103,104,105)
GROUP BY D.userid
ORDER BY D.userid
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JNaYsbYi).